# How to specify both non-authorized and Oauth2 endpoints in a single openapi (v3) specification?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openapi

I am creating an openapi specification (ie "swagger v3") for a existing public api.  This api has non-authorized and oauth2 authorized endpoints.

I've referred to the spec on Github, and searched using Stackoverflow and Google. I found examples of single-use protocol, but not when there were two protocols.

Will some white knight provide an example or document reference about how to code for both protocols using openapi v3?  Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean 1) path `/a` uses OAuth but path `/b` does not use auth, or 2) the same path `/a` can be called both using OAuth and with no auth?

Comment: To clarify, Helen, my query had to do with your #1 example.  This specific instance involves an endpoint that checks the status of the server -- I've seen this in documentation as the /ping endpoint, which shouldn't need to require authentication.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the solution is not to imbed a security object when defining the endpoint.

The code block below is a simplified mock of the code that I used to arrive at this answer.

```
paths:
  /admin/status:
    get:
      tags:
        - admin
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation

components:
  securitySchemes:
    BASIC_AUTH:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
```

All other endpoints in the API I am working on require authentication. For those, the security object will be mandatory.

Comment: That's right. Don't add `security` on the root level of the spec, and instead add `security` to specific operations that require it.